# Can't expand cells with the mouse in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Excel 2007. When I have put dates in the "A" column, I have to write all the dates way down to 31st of the month. While using the mouse, one can write the first date of the month and then scroll the cell from bottom right corner of the cell. My problem is that I can't scroll down, as the plus sign does not appear at the bottom right of the cell (when I am using it). Therefore, I can't use the mouse to add dates by scrolling down. My mouse is otherwise functioning properly.

How can I make that work?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, click on File
 -> Options
 -> Advanced
 -> Under the first section, enable file handle and cell drag-and-drop

Check the box and click OK

Answer (score 0):

take your cursor(Mouse Pointer) to the right bottom corner. you should see a + sign appear.

then click on left mouse key Keep it pressed. Now also press right mouse key and keeping both keys pressed drag down the cell value to the cell you want.

release both mouse keys together now. you shouls see option to copy or fill series etc.

This should work , give this multiple tries before giving up.

Answer (score 0):

In case the answer from @Dave has not solved your issue, you may be experiencing an issue with DPI awareness, as described in the answer to this post:

[Excel Power Query Editor icons and text too small or too large](https://superuser.com/questions/1564991/excel-power-query-editor-icons-and-text-too-small-or-too-large)

I sometimes cannot drag cells down after disconnecting my computer from an external monitor.

Regardless, you can do this from the keyboard:

1. use the arrow keys to select the first cell
2. press <kbd>shift</kbd> and use the down arrow key until you reach the last cell you want to copy down to
3. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to copy down

If you find after doing this that all cells contain the same date, then put this formula under your first date (assuming your first date is in cell A1):

```
=A1+1
```

Then follow the steps above starting from the first cell containing a formula.