# Changing font size in Power Query

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, power-query, powerpivot

I have started to fiddle with `Power Query` a bit and thing that is pretty annoying is size of the font in formula bar and advance editor. Its way to small. Also when you manually enter formulas in custom column its tiny as well. Is there any way that I can make it bigger. Its getting hard to read when you work in it for a long periods. I have added pictures for clarification.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/questions/1564991/excel-power-query-editor-icons-and-text-too-small-or-too-large

Comment: Basically by changing the option(file - option - general - font size), we are changing the font size of whole Excel interface or environment excluding the fonts in ribbon.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase/decrease the zoom level of the Power Query editor with [CTRL][SHIFT][PLUS] and [CTRL][SHIFT][MINUS].  You can reset the zoom to 100% by pressing [CTRL][0].

[image]

This works well in the main editor and the Advanced Editor, but when used on a dialog that is fixed size, the fonts get bigger but the frame does not resize or scroll.  I was able to use a separate app (WinSplit Revolution) to make the form bigger but that's outside the scope of a direct solution.

[image]

As a bit of trivia, this works because the forms are based on IE, which supports the same hotkeys for zoom.

Comment: Is there any way to remember the zoom? It resets everytime one reopens the editor or even moves the window.

Comment: Sorry.  I do not know how to have it remember the settings.